# Как преобразовать строку в объект?

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать строку

```
var str = "{lat:55.74755013048941, lng:37.63388156890869},{lat:55.746245766551574, lng:37.63336658477783},{lat:55.746789256825124, lng:37.63115644454956}"
```

в объект

```
obj:
    {
      lat:55.74755013048941,
      lng:37.63388156890869
    },
    {
      lat:55.746245766551574, 
      lng:37.63336658477783
    },
    {
      lat:55.746789256825124,
      lng:37.63115644454956
    }
```

Comment: Тут нужно сначала переделать строку. Вы могли бы преобразовать её в объект при помощи JSON.parse, но у вас некорректный JSON. Имена переменных нужно брать в кавычки и кроме того у вас тут 3 разных объекта, а не один.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str = "{lat:55.74755013048941, lng:37.63388156890869},{lat:55.746245766551574, lng:37.63336658477783},{lat:55.746789256825124, lng:37.63115644454956}";
var a = eval('({obj:[' + str + ']})');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Вместо eval лучше использовать JSON.stringify

Comment: @PetrChalov `JSON.stringify` это функция, обратная `eval`.

Comment: разве?

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @PetrChalov конечно

Comment: Черт возьми, один раз написал и даже в документацию залез, не заметил. Конечно же `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 4):

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

var str = "{lat:55.74755013048941, lng:37.63388156890869},{lat:55.746245766551574, lng:37.63336658477783},{lat:55.746789256825124, lng:37.63115644454956}";
str = str.replaceAll('lat', '"lat"');
str = str.replaceAll('lng', '"lng"');
var a = JSON.parse('{"obj":[' + str + ']}');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "{lat:55.74755013048941, lng:37.63388156890869},{lat:55.746245766551574, lng:37.63336658477783},{lat:55.746789256825124, lng:37.63115644454956}";
var items = [];

var tokens = str.match(/{[^}]+}/g);
for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    var segments = tokens[i].split(',');
    var item = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < segments.length; j++) {
        var pair = segments[j].replace(/{|}/, '').split(':');
        item[pair[0].trim()] = pair[1];
    }
    items.push(item);    
}

var obj = {obj: items};
console.log(obj);
```